# Where can I buy flowers at Paris (ORY/CDG) Airport?

Tags: airports, paris, shopping, cdg, ory

I am landing at Paris ORY, and then going to CDG by bus to meet my wife in arrivals. And coming back to Paris city (Mid-November).

Is there any flower shop at one of the airports to buy fresh flowers (public/land side only, i.e. after I clear Immigration/Customs at ORY)? I need it before I meet her.

Web sites of airports are not much of help; just showing the mini-markets and some branded showrooms.

Are there any shops? Any personal experience / photos / signs are appreciated. I am willing to walk around to departure areas of any of both airports.

Edit - To be clear, I want to buy/pick/receive myself. And I want to stand there holding it myself to present to her once she comes out after immigration etc. She lands 4 hours after me.

Comment: If you can't find a flower shop at either airport, you can get them delivered with, e.g., [Interflora](https://www.interflora.fr/).

Comment: delivered to the airport??

Comment: @chx No, I want to buy/pick/recieve myself; & want to present it to wife once she clears teh customs/immigration. (She lands 4 hours after me).

Comment: I understand that, @mouviciel doesn't , I am afraid.

Comment: Have you tried calling +33 1 70 36 39 50 ?

Comment: Thanks @chx Yes, Thanks.. Although I am going to ask InterFlora if they can deliver to "me" on airport? Also tomorrow morning will call +33 1 70 36 39 50

Comment: I had a quick look in French at the airport websites and the 'pages jaunes' (yellow pages). Several websites turned up that there are no florists inside the airports themselves, but a few in the local area (1km away from Orly, 4 km away from Roissy). But in that case, you'd have to take public transport or a taxi out.
I am thinking that delivery may be the best case here.
I also don't remember ever seeing a florist in CDG or ORY, but I do remember seeing them in Amsterdam, if you fancy a trip ;)

Comment: Ever is a strong word. There was a florist stall at the CDG train station on Aug 31, 2009 looked quite temporary but for my life I can't remember since.

Comment: @chx : yes delivered to the airport to OP so that he can offer them to his wife. What don’t I understand ?

Comment: @mouviciel  this boggles my mind. Do you have a URL describing how such a thing could possibly work? The logistics of this are beyond me.

Comment: @chx: The business of Interfora is to deliver flowers where you tell them to. If you are afraid they can't find you in a big airport, you can involve your airline and arrange to pickup flowers at their booth.

Comment: Another (expensive) solution is the [concierge service of Paris Airport](http://www.conciergerie-paris-airport.com/langue-english-1.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delivery option mentioned in comments sounds doubtful. As a French, between the notorious lack of service in Paris (and most of France anyway), the language issue, and the lack of a fixed address, I don't see an Interflora driver even bothering... I've used Interflora, while living abroad, to send flowers to my mom, to her home, and getting them to guarantee a delivery on the right day (her birthday), even planning in advance, was hard enough.

Since you have four hours, I would recommend this:

- From ORY take a bus to Montparnasse ("Le Bus Direct" Line 1)
- In Montparnasse buy some flowers.
- Get on Le Bus Direct Line 4 to CDG
- Meet the wife.

[image: Florists around Gare Montparnasse]

Comment: My experience with Interflora is much more positive.

Comment: Good for you. Mine repeatedly wasn't. And good luck if one doesn't speak French either.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
Here is  what I actually did: I just bought it from my starting city before I reached airport, asked the Trader Joe employee to cut the stems & make the bunch shorter; just put it into the carry on suitcase. On arrival after about 7 hours, they were fine.

==================================

I have accepted [@dda](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67108/dda)'s [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/104008/38009), and here in this I am just documenting what I found from Google, based on his suggestions:

1. Landing at ORY Airport to Montparnasse
2. Line 01 ORY to Montparnasse (20-30 Minutes Duration, 20 Minutes frequency, Single Ticket (Billet Simple) EUR 10/-
3. Buy Flowers Montparnasse (Flowers in French Fleurs)
4. Board Line 04 Montparnasse to CDG (70-80 Minutes Duration, 30 Minutes frequency, Single Ticket EUR 17/-)

Total Time (Minutes):

- 30 - Line 01 ORY to Montparnasse
- 30 - Buy Flowers
- 80 - Line 04 Montparnasse to CDG
- 30 - Frequency (Might miss one with just a minute) OR Breather

Total About 3 Hours At Most. It will be kind of race from the moment I am landside at ORY.

Also, the easiest no frills but unromantic option will be to not to do this & just Board Line 03, Direct from ORY to CDG (1 Hour 20 Minutes).

References:
1. Paris Le-Bus http://www.lebusdirect.com/en/

Comment: Did you look for a flower selling stand or shop for people coming to collect people from arrivals? (That is what I have seen in several other airports but as I have never been landside in CDG, closer than inside a train, I would not know whether they are there.)